# locals not working for controller rendering in rails 5.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5.1

I have a controller action that renders a printable version of the page using a `print.html.erb` template. The controller code is:

```
def print
    @title = 'Print - Drill'
    render :show, layout: 'print', locals: { back_pth: drill_path(@drill) }
end
```

and in `print.html.erb` there is a line:

```
<%= link_to 'Back', back_pth, class: 'print_link' %>
```

but this generates an error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error:
       undefined local variable or method `back_pth' for #<#<Class:0x007fd6004e1230>:0x007fd5f7da57d0>
```

The print template is called by many different controller actions, so how do I fix this?  This code worked in rails 5.0.6.

Comment: print.html.erb is the layout ?

Comment: Did you try `render :show, back_pth: drill_path(@drill), layout: 'print'` ?

Comment: Just wonder what is `back_pth`, helper method ?

Comment: 7urkm3n, it is not a helper it is a local variable for render.

Comment: Akovtunov, your suggestion does not work, just throws and exception. If you see FaraPantankar's answer below it looks like it is a bug in 5.1.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by FarazPantakar this is an [issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/31680#issuecomment-363287687) in the rails 5.1 ActionController.  The issue report has a workaround which is to use local_assigns in the html, so the link becomes

```
<%= link_to 'Back', local_assigns[:back_pth], class: 'print_link' %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not very sure if this classifies as an answer but [this](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/31680) might be what you're experiencing?

Perhaps, for now, you could move your code to the `show` action as that'd work even though it doesn't work inside the layout.

Comment: It does look like a bug introduced in rails 5.1.4.  In each case, there is a corresponding show action, the idea is that when someone wants a printable version of the page, they click a link to the print action, that provides a printable version, click the 'back' link takes you back the screen viewable show action.